# How to look at Rubidium frequency standard using the oscilloscope?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency, oscillator, electrical-signal

This question is about the checking hardware, please help if someone who has done it before.

I have the Rubidium frequency standard: http://www.thinksrs.com/products/PRS10.htm

and the Oscilloscope: https://www.atecorp.com/products/tektronix/tds3034

From the Oscilloscope, I want to look at 1PPS and 10MHz from the Rubidium frequency standard, **How to do that?**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the Oscilloscope, I want to check 1PPS and 10MHz from the Rubidium frequency standard, How to do that?

Not at all.

From your oscilloscope's product page:

> Accuracy: 200 ppm

That's relatively bad, even for cheap measurement equipment.

From the rubidium oscillator's datasheet:

> Accuracy at shipping: $\pm 5 \cdot 10^{-11}$

which is

$$ 
\frac{2\cdot 10^{-4}}{5\cdot 10^{-11}}\,
$$

i.e. **4 Million times more accurate** than your oscilloscope promises to be.

I'd very much expect a comparable difference in oscillator phase noise.

In other words: your rubidium clock is so much better than your oscilloscope that you can only measure your oscilloscope by observing the rubidium clock, not the other way around.

Generally, you'll have a hard time finding an oscillator that beats your rubidium clock in accuracy, so that you can asses it. You can compare long-term against a good GPS-disciplined oscillator, or against other, more expensive atomic clocks.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but I would like to know a little more about rubidium clock, how to observe the rubidium clock?

Comment: what do you mean, "observe"?

Comment: I want to see microsecond variation, is it vary? how much is it vary? How much differences there from PPS output to rubidium clock? Microsecond in variation I should be able to see if I were change this scope trigger on 1 of these PPS output and then I look at the others. And since system is 300MHz bandwidth and I can see of the other of 3 nanoseconds of variation, so microsecond variation in a few, if I trigger on 1 and watch the other, what does it do? That is **my goal to check Rubidium frequency standard using the oscilloscope**

Comment: **read my answer**. You **can not** use your oscilloscope to verify something that is 4 million times *better* than your oscilloscope. That's like using a scale designed to weigh elephants to verify the weight of a single dust particle. The whole point of having a frequency standard is to calibrate the rest of your equipment.

Comment: and where does your whole microsecond come from? A clock with an accuracy of $5\cdot 10^{-11}$ might have a microsecond error when you compare it after a full day with a theoretical "perfect" clock. Not that you are likely to ever have access to a clock that is much more perfect than this Rubidium clock. AAAARGH, now I want to have your Rubidium clock for myself.

Comment: I repeat myself: You **can not** check your rubidium clock with your oscilloscope. That'd be like trying to check the diameter of a single hair by putting it next to a cricket field. Seriously.

Comment: Here what I am trying to do? I am collecting GPS data and calculate time delay estimation. Assume the algorithms are right, but when I have data collected, I put in the Matlab, and it gives me time delay estimation, but the time seems to be wrong, the expectation for this time is about in nanosecond, but I get in microsecond, that's why I need to check every single part in the system.

Comment: @ Marcus Müller: I understand. And Thank you very much.

Comment: @NateDuong you probably want to write a new question explaining exactly that, including a detailed description of the components involved. But: any estimator has a variance, and especially for GPS receivers, that gets very clear when you think about how your smartphone's location accuracy increases (variance decreases) when the receiver has had more signal to integrate over and receives the signal of more satellites. A timing error of a microsecond is pretty much for a GPS receiver, however – this points to a bug in your estimator.

Comment: is it possible if I want to look at Rubidium frequency standard on the oscilloscope? I want to see its behavior.

Comment: It's a periodic signal. What behaviour are you hoping to see? Do you know how to basically use an oscilloscope? It's the most boring thing you see. If something is not behaving perfectly periodical in that signal, it's very likely a measurement error of your oscilloscope. Again, rubidium clock >> oscilloscope sampling clock, by a factor of 4 farking million.

Comment: yes, I do know basically use it. according to this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMpLNeHIAeU&t=1s : but it is not showing the connection, I just don't want to damage this Rubidium.

Comment: I don't understand - either you know how to use an oscilloscope, or you don't know how to safely connect a device to an oscilloscope. Anyway, we're clearly leaving the field that can even remotely be related to signal processing. I mean, if you need help wiring up an oscilloscope, how about asking someone in the same lab? It's a lot easier to do when standing in front of the device...

Comment: Can we measure time vary of 10MHz between 2 rubidium clocks using oscilloscope?

Comment: oooh GAWD. Stop it. Your rubidium clock is very likely the most reliable piece of equipment you have. Your code is bad and bug-ridden. Stop blaming your equipment. But: no. How should that work? these two clocks should have less than $10^{-10}$ in frequency difference. Tell me how you'd be able to tell that with an oscillator in your Oscilloscope that's, I repeat, 4 farking millions time worse. I'll simply stop replying, this is annoying, sorry. You can try to use one as clock input for the oscilloscope, if that supports it, but since the clock generation circutry will have far worse…

Comment: … performance than what would be necessary to assess the quality of your rubidium clocks... What about you try to understand a bit about oscilloscopes and oscillators, on your own?

Comment: I am so sorry to ask you many times. I will not ask you again. Thank you for being patient with me. Admit, the rubidium clock is better than the scope, but I just want to check this rubidium are still working or not because once we dropped it on the floor? and I have not asked you anything about the code!

Answer (score 0):

> but I just want to check this rubidium are still working or not because once we dropped it on the floo

Short Rant:

OK. we have a **sixteen messages conversation** under my answer after you wrote a question, and only **four full days** after asking, it occurs to you that **oops I dropped my multi-thousand-dollar frequency standard** might be a relevant piece of info???

So, this is clearly no signal processing problem. You might have ruined a piece of equipment that someone else might rely on with their PhD or job. Find someone who's actually competent enough to diagnose the device, if in doubt, call the company that produced it. They have calibration services, and will be able to do that properly.

A "possibly broken", "checked only by a so-and-so competent" measurement standard is worse than not having a measurement standard; it might ruin future research. It's mandatory you inform the person in charge of the lab, and clearly mark the device as being of unknown state of functionality.